# Namespaced actionmailer in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have a namespace in my app called "storyed".

I have a `storyed_contact_mailer` in my mailers folder, and the views for the mailer inside the `storyed` folder in the views folder.

My contacts controller, which is in the namespace and defined like this: `class Storyed::StoryedContactsController < Storyed::StoryedController`, calls the deliver method in storyed_contact_mailer. It WORKS in development.

In production, on Heroku I get this error, which I can't figure out:

```
>  NameError (uninitialized constant
> Storyed::StoryedContactsController::StoryedContactMailer):
> 2012-02-04T05:32:35+00:00 app[web.1]:  
> app/controllers/storyed/storyed_contacts_controller.rb:12:in `block in
> create' 2012-02-04T05:32:35+00:00 app[web.1]: 
> 2012-02-04T05:32:35+00:00 app[web.1]:  2012-02-04T05:32:35+00:00
> app[web.1]:  
> app/controllers/storyed/storyed_contacts_controller.rb:10:in `create'
```

I did at one point have the `storyed_contact_mailer` inside a storyed folder in the mailers folder, but it still didn't work. Any ideas why this fails in production?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Not namespacing the mailer at all 'removing the Storyed' part has fixed the problem.